# What would be the Russian word for "ownership"?

Tags: перевод, semantics

What would be the Russian word for "ownership", in the meaning of owning a topic or a task and not owning property?
The best equivalent I've found is "oтветственность". However, "responsibility" and not "ownership" will be a more accurate meaning for that one.

Comment: There is no single equivalent, it all context-dependent. "Владеть", "быть ответственным", "заниматься" may all be applicable here.

Comment: Can you provide some examine sentences? Do you mean "take ownership of this job", as in take initiative for it, take responsibility for getting it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're talking about slang used in IT (which I have a strong suspicion we are), then the terms "владелец" and "владение" are actually quite common, so one can hear something like this:

> Коллеги, а кто владеет у нас этой компонентой, с кем мне в принципе поговорить об этом?

Some actual quotes from [habr](https://habr.com/ru/search/?target_type=posts&q=%5B%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%5D&order_by=date):

- Типичные ошибки Владельца продукта в Скраме. ([link](https://habr.com/ru/post/478200/))
- Договориться о политиках владения кодом и превратить это в процесс ([link](https://habr.com/ru/company/miro/blog/539768/))

By the way, the same analogy exists for ownership as a term used in some programming languages for describing memory models, so it's "владение и заимствование в Rust".

Of course, this doesn't cancel out the existence of just "продакт-оунер".

Comment: It can be applied to IT. Yes. However, the intent is for this term in leadership in the corporate world in general.

Comment: "Владелец" is a fairly recent calque from English. I don't believe it is much used outside of IT context.

Comment: @Alexander quite frankly I never heard owner in this context in non IT context in English as well - it's usually, don't know something like in charge of, their area of responsibility etc.

Answer (score 5):

As a native Russian language speaker, I can say that "ответственность" is the accurate word in this case.

Comment: I also am a native speaker. The issue is that responsibility and ownership are similar but they are far from synonyms. I'm trying to find a word that conveys that difference.
Unless you're trying to say that this distinction is not present in Russian?

Comment: Owned property is an asset: it can be sold to someone else for a profit, it can be used and enjoyed by the owner in beneficial ways. By contrast, if a task is "owned", this is not an asset but a burden. No one will pay you in order to become the new owner. This usage of the word "ownership" (of a task) is relatively new in English, it didn't exist a few decades ago. It's a neologism, business-related jargon. You are held responsible for the task, you are accountable. In a more positive sense, you are in charge of it, with decision-making ability. But "in charge of" is still ответсвенный.

Answer (score 2):

There's another translation option for this word - "обладание"

Владение кем-, чем-либо как собственностью ◆ Война, ведущаяся с турками за обладание великим княжеством Сусиана и за возвращение отнятых оттоманами земель, принадлежащих персидской империи, предоставляет ей для этого великолепную возможность. Людмила Старикова, «Театральная жизнь России в эпоху Елизаветы Петровны», 2005 г.

Comment: "обладатель подсистемы" - I like it)

Comment: «Обладать чувством юмора».

Answer (score -1):

In your context, *владение* is wrong and *ответственность* is the more suitable term.
Since you don't "own" your work (task) per se, but are assigned to do it.

*Владеть задачей* is bad calque from project managment terminology.
Most examples from Russian IT are a mix of anglicisms and Runglish.